# SSRS How to hide parameters/grouping panels in design mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

[image][image][image]

How to hide parameters/grouping panels in design mod. Or in other words uncheck these menu options so panels hidden when a report opened in design mode. Every time I open any report, it opens parameters and grouping panels as well. There must be any option not to open these panels by default with every report opened. I am tired and found nothing on web. Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What I need here is to close by default for every report I open. I know how to close it one by one for all reports opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-Click on a blank part of your report, then View -> Parameters

Comment: I have not received any answer or even comment for my question. Still looking for any good solution...

Comment: The methis I described does affect all reports, you only need to set it once.

Comment: I dont know I tried the same before but in my case it did'nt work. Well thanks.